# Cloning tr and removing cloned tr

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having a problem removing my cloned tr.. my cloning function is working perfectly but whenever im trying to add a remove button on the right side nothings happen .. please help me

jQuery :

```
$(".addjob").click(function(){
        var $clone = $('table.tbll tr.cloneme:first').clone();
         console.log($clone);
         $clone.append("<td><div class='rmv' >Remove</div></td>");
         $('table.tbll').append($clone);    
 });

        $(".rmv").click(function(){
            alert("wee");
           // $(this).parents('td').remove();
        });
```

HTML :

```
<table cellspacing="10" class="tbll" >
<tr>
<td>Choose Sub Heading</td><td><select name="subheading_id" style="min-width:145Px">
            <option value="1" Sub heading Me</option>
            <option value="2" Sub heading Me 2</option>     
    </select></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr classs="cloneme">
<td>Choose Job Title</td><td><select name="jobtitles_id" style="min-width:145Px"><?php
            <option value="a" >A</option>   
            <option value="b" >B</option>   
            <option value="c" >C</option>       
                    <option value="none" >None</option> 
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="addjob" >Add another Job Title</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please help me. I dont know what to do

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need a event delegation: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/h9pH5/</kbd>

```
$(".addjob").click(function () {
   var $clone = $('table.tbll tr.cloneme:first').clone();
   console.log($clone);
   $clone.append("<td><div class='rmv' >Remove</div></td>");
   $('table.tbll').append($clone);
});

$('.tbll').on('click', '.rmv', function () {
   alert("wee");
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

and in your html you have multiple `s` in

```
`<tr classs="cloneme">`
      //--^---here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your remove click function as it is will not work on dynamically added elements. You have to use jquery `.on`

```
$('body').on('click', '.rmv',function(){
    alert("wee");
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Also, you still have `classs` for cloneme, correct it to `class`.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Z5kt/

EDIT: I have changed your `.parents('td')` to `.closest('tr')` assuming you wanted to remove the whole row. Please change this accordingly.

Note: .closest helps find the required element up the hierarchy and helps you avoid elements returned by `.parents()`

EDIT 2: Here is a version using .live for use before jquery 1.7

```
$('.rmv').live('click', function(){
    alert("wee");
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: it has an error on my console.. im using firebug btw.. here is the error "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$('body').on('click', '.rmv',function(){"

Comment: Remove will remove the newly added element, so hopefully $(this).parents('td').remove(); should be changed to $(this).parents('tr').remove();..

Comment: @user1954395 Had done that in the fiddle. Not in the code sample. Will update. Thanks for pointing it out.